# Module odoo 8 - how to call another module in mine

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i create a module in odoo and i would like to know how to call another module in mine. For example, I need the user module, Human Resources and others. please help

Answer (score 2):

In the file `__openerp__.py` you must specify the dependency on the module or the modules you need separated by `,`:

```
'depends': ['hr', 'other_module']
```

When you want to use the models of these modules in your classes you can use search and browse methods. Example:

```
self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('id', '=', your_id)], context)
```

I hope this help you!